# Согласование в падеже

Tags: согласование

Он учился в медресе при II
мечети Казани (ныне «Апанаевская»).
Или "Апанаевской"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Он учился в медресе при II мечети Казани (ныне Апанаевская мечеть).**

Выражение в скобках является **вставной конструкцией**, поэтому согласование не требуется.

Comment: Спорная логика: раз вставная конструкция, значит согласование не требуется. Примеры вставных конструкций: Отец лишился обыкновенной своей твёрдости, и горесть его (**обыкновенно немая**) изливалась в горьких жалобах (Пушкин) ; Нет, вы (**или ты**) этого не должны знать! (Лермонтов (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/727-211_vstavnye_slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Я бы сказал, что здесь вставная конструкция — это целое    предложение, поэтому согласование не требуется.

Comment: Не требуется - это значит  не является обязательным условием, и тогда  вы можете выбирать нужный вам вариант. Здесь выбрано предложение: ныне (это) Апанаевская мечеть. Сравнить: Он учился в медресе при II (ныне Апанаевской) мечети Казани . В этом случае название согласовано.